# How to open a class definition in a new tab in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, navigation

In Xcode, if I want to open a class definition, I right-click the class name and select "Jump to definition".

```
let service = MyApiService()
```

Sometimes it opens the class in a new tab, sometimes it opens the class in the current tab. How can I open the class always in a new tab? How can I go back to the previous location from the new location?

Answer (score 0):

To always open class in a new tab, you need to make some changes in Xcode Preferences. Click **Xcode in Menu bar > Preferences > Navigation** and make below changes

[image]

Now when you right-click the class name press the **options** key along with **click** (on 'Jump to definition') and it will always open Class in a new tab.

And to navigate/ go to the previous location use the below controls in the navigation pane above the editor (where class names are displayed)

[image]